# Telegram Bot Error - telegram.error.BadRequest: Button_data_invalid

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to  make a telegram bot with the `telegram` and `telegram.ext` libraries on Python. I try to pass `callback_data` for a button as a parameter for inline keyboard, but when it comes to add the keyboard as `reply_markup`, it sends the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\micke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 279, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self)
    File "C:\Users\micke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\callbackqueryhandler.py", line 143, in handle_update
    return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
    File ".\__init__.py", line 121, in button
    reply_markup=reply_markup
    File "C:\Users\micke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 60, in decorator
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\micke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 85, in decorator
    result = self._request.post(url, data, timeout=kwargs.get('timeout'))
    File "C:\Users\micke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 273, in post
    **urlopen_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\micke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 210, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Button_data_invalid`

The code is the following:

`p1 = "%s(@%s)"%(query.from_user.first_name,query.from_user.username)
        text = "<b>⚔Duel</b>\nChallenger %s is ready!\nWaiting for an opponent..."%p1
        args = '{"next":"player2","p1":"%s","text":"%s"}'%(p1,text)
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(kb.kb(op = "data",args = args))
        bot.edit_message_text(
                              text=text,
                              inline_message_id=query.inline_message_id,
                              parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML,
                              reply_markup=reply_markup
                              )`

Also, the code for the keyboard is:

`class kb:
    def kb(op = None, args = None):
        if op == 'data':
            keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Join", callback_data = args)]]`

I don't really know where am I mistaken. It works well when instead of `args` I assign static text to `callback_data`

What do you think it could be?

Comment: what data are you sending as args? what type of an object is that? (you may need use type('')  to check its type)

Comment: @tashakori I'm sending the args always as string type, and always between 'simple quotes' trying to avoid problems with it

Answer (score 17):

Probably data size, you passing, is exceeding the maximum allowed bytes of 64.
Here is the [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton).
You can get size of data in bytes as followed.

```
len('YOUR DATA'.encode('utf-8'))
```